# How do i replace '\' by '\\' in C++ to deal with escape sequences?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, replace

I want to deal with escape sequences, if I store a string in variable such as "a\b\ncd\ref" then I want output same as the string I given i.e, "a\b\ncd\ref" .
Compiler should not interpret. I tried using regex_replace and many things else, but I couldn't achieve anything. It would be of great help if someone could suggest a solution.

Comment: Please post what you have tried already. Only at compile time will `\n` etc be converted, so the doubling-up of the backslashes should be in your source code, therefore your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Have a look here: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/ : basically prefixing the string with R should do what you want : A raw string literal starts with R"( and ends in )" : string raw_str=R"(First line.\nSecond line.\nEnd of message.\n)";

Comment: Use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write a string like this,

```
"a\b\ncd\ref"
```

You have to escape the backslash and write \\ instead of just one \.

```
char* c = "a\\b\\ncd\\ref";
std::cout << c;
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: That should be `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

What mechanism are you using to "store a string in a variable"? What I mean is, are you doing:

`std::string foo = "a\b\c";`

or

`std::string foo;
std::cin >> foo; // Or some other stream operator such as std::ifstream`

?

If it's the latter, the compiler will automatically add the escape sequence and you shouldn't worry. The escape sequence is only necessary to tell the compiler the hard-coded string in the source-file represents a special ASCII character. If it's not hard-coded, you're getting the correct byte and don't need to prepend.